# Making categories appear conditionally in the frontend with radio button in WordPress custom field

Tags: wordpress, radio-button, categories

**Problem solved:**
I would like to thank the user @kofeigen for his interest. He did such a great job. He made the system I wanted work exactly.

I added a custom field with a radio option to the category edit page. By selecting these radio buttons with 2 options, I want to determine whether the relevant category will appear in the category list in the frontend.

I cannot add the "checked" code dynamically to save the radio button as selected. I want to intervene in the category list that I previously listed in the front end. According to this option, I want to specify a condition in the category list in the front end and list the category names accordingly. I'm new to PHP and JavaScript. I'm more newbie to Javascript than PHP. Can you help with this?

**Details:** I think the radio button selected is recorded with javascript or PHP and the front end should call whichever radio button is selected in the query. I can't preserve the radio markup when saving the category.

```
add_action ( 'subjects_edit_form_fields', 'subjects_edit_tab_fields_callback', 10, 2 );
function subjects_edit_tab_fields_callback($tag, $taxonomy) {
$tab_id = $tag->term_id;
$cat_meta = get_option( "subjects_$tab_id");
?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="tab_menu_select"><?php _e('option to show in category list'); ?></label></th>
    <span class="description"><?php _e('Appear in the category list?'); ?></span>
    <td>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Show in Tab Menu</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">Doesn't Show in Tab Menu</label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

**Let me make the question clearer:**

1. As an administrator, I want to select the "show category" radio button on the category edit page and update the category.
2. I do not want to see the category name that I specified with the
   radio button in the tab menu tab that I specially created on the
   home page of my website.
3. Because if I list all the categories listed in the tab menu I
   created on the home page, the menu list will be very long. Also, I
   do not want to display every category name in the same region.

**My fiction:**

1. Adding a custom field with a radio button to the edit category page.

   - I added the custom field.
2. Making a selection (Show/Don't show) with the radio button and saving it as selected. - Here's the real problem.
3. Category marked "Do not show"; Don't show it when listing the category in the frontend. - Categories are listed, no problem. Then I think I can specify a condition and list it again conditionally. This part is easier if I fix the radio button issue.

In fact, it may even be a single button. In other words, if it is checked, it should show it, if it is not checked, it should not show it. The checked category should not appear when listing categories name in the frontend, or it could be the other way around. the result is the same.

**As a single radio button:**

```
add_action ( 'subjects_edit_form_fields', function( $tag ){
  $radio_select = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, 'tab_menu_select', true );
  ?>
  <tr class='form-field'>
    <th scope='row'><label for='tab_menu_select_list'><?php _e('Showing in tab menu'); ?></label></th>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' name='radio_select' id='radio_select' value='<?php echo $radio_select; ?>' <?php if ($_POST['radio_select'] == 'radio_select') echo 'checked'; ?>>
    </td>
    </tr> <?php
  });
add_action ( 'edited_subjects', function( $term_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['radio_select'] ) )
    update_term_meta( $term_id , 'tab_menu_select', $_POST['radio_select'] );
});
```

**My tab menu code block where I list the categories in the frontend:**

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center my-5 px-md-5">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs d-flex flex-column flex-md-row justify-content-center" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php
    $cats = get_terms([
      'taxonomy'       =>'subjects',
      'hide_empty'     =>false,
      'orderby'        =>'name',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'order'          =>'DESC']);
      ?>
      <?php foreach($cats as $cat) { ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <style>a.nav-link.active{background-color: #26ae61ba!important;color: #fff!important;border: none;}</style>
        <a class="nav-link <?php echo ($i == 1) ? 'active': ''; ?>" id="nav-startup-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-startup" aria-selected="true"> <?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?></a>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <?php $i = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach($cats as $cat){ ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php
        $args = array(
          'post_type'       => 'custompost',
          'post_status'     => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'  => -1,
          'tax_query'       =>array(
            array('taxonomy'  => 'subjects',
              'field'           =>'term_id',
              'terms'           =>$cat->term_id,
              'operator'        => 'IN'
            ),
          ),
        ); ?>
        <div class="tab-pane <?php echo ($i == 1) ? 'active show': 'fade'; ?>" id="<?php echo $cat->slug ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-startup-tab">
          <div class="row">
            <?php
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if( $the_query->have_posts()){
              while( $the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post();
                $imagepath = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'large');
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <img class="mt-4 mb-2" src="<?php echo $imagepath[0];?>" alt="Tab Menu Category Post Image">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h6><?php the_title();?></h6></a>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; } ?>
              <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason the show/hide status is stored using `options` (e.g. `get_option()`)? This status is a property of the taxonomy term (like `name`, `slug`, etc.) For your purposes it seems to make more sense to store this status as a *term meta* value. *Term meta* is linked to the taxonomy term by `term_id`. This allows you to filter the list of categories for the front-end using a [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/). Can you use *term meta*?

Comment: I want it to be more practical, that is, to have the option to hide it directly by marking it. The user may not want to see every category in the tab menu template on the specially prepared home page. For this reason, you can use this show & hide option on the categories editing page in the admin panel. Because there are many categories, it will appear as a large list. This may be bad in terms of appearance and usage. Just choose whichever category you want. This is all I could do with the codes. I need help with more.

Comment: Ok, thanks. When you say: *The user may not want to see every category...* are you saying that the show/hide status for each category is user specific? So, **User A** might have **Category X** *displayed*, while **User B** might have **Category X** *hidden*? Can you please update your question with the code for the tab menu template from the specially prepared home page? In particular, I would like to see the code that generates the list of categories.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. It has nothing to do with users. I detailed the question.

Comment: Great. These references in the WordPress documentation might be helpful along with my answer: [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/), [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/), [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Term_Query/__construct/), [WP_Meta_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/__construct/) and the [edit_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_taxonomy/) action hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippets below have been tested, and should fit your needs.

### `flexRadioDefault`

`flexRadioDefault` is a property of the `subjects` custom taxonomy terms. When an administrator edits a `subjects` taxonomy term, a value (0 or 1) is assigned to `flexRadioDefault` in the [wp_termmeta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_termmeta) database table for that specific taxonomy term (`flexRadioDefault` and the term are linked in the `wp_termmeta` table by `term_id`). `flexRadioDefault` is the `meta_key`. `0` or `1` is the `meta_value`.

`subjects` taxonomy terms that do not yet have a `flexRadioDefault` term meta key will be shown by default (i.e. as if they had the key with a value of `1`).

### Update for the admin term.php edit taxonomy page

```
add_action( 'subjects_edit_form_fields', 'subjects_edit_tab_fields_callback', 10, 2 );
function subjects_edit_tab_fields_callback( $tag, $taxonomy ) {
    $term_id = $tag->term_id;

    // Check if the taxonomy term already has the term meta key 'flexRadioDefault'.
    // If it doesn't, use '1' (show) as the default value.
    $metadata_exists = metadata_exists( 'term', $term_id, 'flexRadioDefault' );
    if ( $metadata_exists ) {

        // @see {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/}
        // The third argument (a boolean) determines if the meta_value should be read as
        // a single value (compared to being read as an array of values).
        $flexRadioDefault = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'flexRadioDefault', true );
    } else {
        $flexRadioDefault = 1;
    }
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="tab_menu_select"><?php _e('option to show in category list'); ?></label></th>
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Appear in the category list?'); ?></span>
        <td>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" value="1" <?php checked( $flexRadioDefault, 1 ); ?>>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">Show in Tab Menu</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault2" value="0" <?php checked( $flexRadioDefault, 0 ); ?>>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">Doesn't Show in Tab Menu</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

### Process the radio button value after form submission

```
add_action( 'edit_subjects', 'update_subject_status', 10, 3 );
function update_subject_status( $term_id, $tt_id, $args ) {
    if ( ! isset( $args )
        || 'subjects' != $args['taxonomy']
        || ! isset( $args['term_id'] )
    ) {
        return;
    }

    update_term_meta( $term_id, 'flexRadioDefault', $args['flexRadioDefault'] );
}
```

### Update for the `WP_Term_Query` used to get the list of custom taxonomy terms in the tab menu code block

The query searches for taxonomy terms that:

1. have the `flexRadioDefault` term meta key with a value of `1` (show)
   **OR**
2. do not have the `flexRadioDefault` term meta key at all (since they are shown by default).

The only taxonomy terms that will be excluded are those that have the `flexRadioDefault` term meta key with a value of `0` (hide).

```
$meta_args = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'      => 'flexRadioDefault',
        'value'    => 1,
        'type'     => 'UNSIGNED',
        'compare'  => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key'      => 'flexRadioDefault',
        'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
);

$cats = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'subjects',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'number'     => '',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'fields'     => 'all',
        'meta_query' => $meta_args
    )
);
```

### Update to `WP_Query` used in the tab menu code block

`'operator' => 'IN'` should be used when the `tax_query` `terms` property is assigned to an array. Your `terms` property is assigned to an integer. So, `'operator' => 'IN'` should be removed.

Comment: I'm wondering how to thank you. Thank you very much for your interest. You are great. It's super. There is no problem now. It works exactly as I want. May life always be the way you want it to be. @kofeigen

Comment: Thanks. Glad it works.  Another useful reference is the documentation for the WordPress [checked](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/) function. It conditionally adds the `checked` attribute to the checkbox `<input>` element. It sometimes isn't clear which are PHP vs. WordPress functions.